# In Html word is shuffling when i copy paste arabic text in input box .

Tags: javascript, css, html, arabic-support

I copy this text

> يف عام

and paste in input box its give me output like this

> عام يف

Comment: Something about the text direction probably, check https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-dir

Answer (score 1):

Set the direction of the Textbox

```
input {
   direction: rtl; 
}
```

Comment: ya i already set this but not working its just changing position